# NS2: How to measure queueing delay

Tags: ns2

I need a tcl or awk script that can be used queueing delay in my simulation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk scripts like below

```
   if($4 == "AGT" && $1 == "s") {
      start_time[$6] = $2;
} else if(($7 == "cbr") && ($1 == "r")) {
    end_time[$6] = $2;
}
```

now you can calculate by subtraction..